# compare 2 cells in excel by using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to compare 2 cells' value and see whether they are match or not.
I know how to do it on excel but I dont' know how to put it vba code.

**Input & output:**

1. The value of cell A1 is already in the excel.
2. Manually enter a value in Cell B1.
3. click on a button_click sub to see whether the value on 2 cells are the same or not.
4. Show "Yes" or "No" on cell C1

**Excel formula:**

```
=IF(A1=B1,"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IIF function in VBA. It is similar to the Excel IF

```
[c1] = IIf([a1] = [b1], "Yes", "No")
```

Comment: This isn't standard practice in VBA.  If you are trying to make your code portable, I'd suggest either Gary's answer on assigning to a button or my answer on using onchange event.

Answer (score 4):

Give this a try:

```
Sub CompareCells()
    If [a1] = [b1] Then
        [c1] = "yes"
    Else
        [c1] = "no"
    End If
End Sub
```

*Assign this code to the button.*

Comment: Thanks Gary. Great help!

Answer (score 2):

```
If (Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value) Then
    Range("C1").Value = "Yes"
Else
    Range("C1").Value = "No"
End If
```

Comment: That isn't proper VBA syntax.

Comment: Fairly certain this isn't valid code in *any* language. Looks like you've mixed together VBA and C#. And even if the syntax was correct, this does not do what the question asks.

Comment: If (Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value) Then
        MsgBox ("Equals")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not Equals")
    End If

Comment: Syntax works, but still doesn't answer the original Q.

Comment: If (Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value) Then
     Range("C1").Value = "Yes"
 Else
     Range("C1").Value = "No"
 End If

Answer (score 0):

Here is an on change Sub (code MUST go in the sheet module).  It will only activate if you change a cell in column B.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    If Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value Then
        Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = "Yes"
    Else
        Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = "No"
    End If
End Sub
```

For the record, this doesn't use a button, but it accomplishes your goal of calculating if the two cells are equal any time you manually enter data into cells in Col B.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CompareandHighlight()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheets
    Dim r As Range

    n = Worksheets("Indices").Range("E:E").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    Dim match As Boolean
    Dim valE As Double
    Dim valI As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = 2 To n
        valE = Worksheets("Indices").Range("E" & i).Value
        valI = Worksheets("Indices").Range("I" & i).Value

        If valE = valI Then

        Else:                           
            Worksheets("Indices").Range("E" & i).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```