# comparing the content of two cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare the content of two cells in macro

RC1=2.0
RC2=2

I am using `if(RC1=RC2,"''","x")` for this which prints `x` for the above input but 2.0 and 2 are same, I need it to be `''` in this case, please suggest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare 2 cells in excel by using vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071459/compare-2-cells-in-excel-by-using-vba)

Comment: my question is that it is returning false after comparison of 2 and 2.0 by using the above method , is there any other method to compare and get the result as true?

Comment: Try to use [Val Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264296.aspx).

Comment: Prakash Singh please consider changing the right answer to @CLR , mine is really off as the comment by Ralph explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your failing 'code' suggests you're merely using a formula:

```
if(RC1=RC2,"''","x")
```

If you are happy using a formula to test them, you could use:

```
IF(VALUE(RC1)=VALUE(RC2),"''","x")
```

Be aware though, a blank cell has a `VALUE` of 0 (zero) so an empty cell would match a cell containing `0.00`

Comment: Just in case the OP is really using VBA (as the tag suggests) you might also want to include the VBA solution with `Val()` instead of `Value()`: `MsgBox Val("2.0")=2`

Comment: but by using the above formula i will not be able to validate other cases like 1.9999 and 1, it will return true if i use the formula suggested by you

Comment: No, `value(1)` definitely does not equate to `value(1.9999)` with that formula. It would return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

**First and foremost**

You are trying to compare two different data types, let's say consider that one is an [integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx), which does not have decimal values, and the other one a [double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx), with a decimal.

I would suggest you to have a better look at [data types in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx).

Hence we will need to [convert the types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/gg278896.aspx) to one that is the same for both cells with `CDbl()` to convert them to `double`. To put it simply, since `integers` are a simpler form of `doubles` we will use the more complete type of both.

**Code to compare the types**

```
Sub COMPARING_TYPES()

Dim a As Double, b As Double

' Let's assume the both values are numeric
a = CDbl(Cells(1, 1))
b = CDbl(Cells(2, 1))

If a = b Then
    ' Other code to execute when the values are matching
End If

End Sub
```

This is all considering you want to compare the numbers in a VBA code.

Comment: Excel does not care if you compare `Integer` with `Double`, `Byte`, or `Long`. Consider `Dim a as Integer, b as Byte, c as Double, d as Long` and then `a = 2`, `b = 2`, `c = 2`, `d = 2` afterwards you can verify yourself that `MsgBox a = b` is as much `True` as is `MsgBox b = c` and `MsgBox c = d` (automatic / implicit conversion). So, @CLR is right and the only possible problem can be that `RC1` contains the string `2.0` (and **not** the number formatted with one decimal showing). Hence, he / she is proposing to convert the string to a number with `Value`.

Comment: You are indeed right, I just tried it and it worked whichever the type of the variable was. Sorry for the inconvenience. I don't know why the OP gave me the right answer though.

Comment: There is no inconvenience at all. Don't worry. Also, your comment would be right for most programming languages such as C++, Java, SQL, etc. Yet, VBA is very forgiving and allows for a lot of things which would be considered inconceivable in other *real* programming languages. This is not the only thing in this respect. Other things are (1) implicit conversions (2) unqualified references (3) no need to set objects to `Nothing` for garbage collection ... and so on.