# How to Check if Two Values Are The Same in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to make sure two values are EQUAL in Excel. On my main excel page, I have four text boxes that are to be filled with specific codes (IE: ABC, BCD, DCE) and they have to match a list I have populated in column O. If they don't match that column, I want to make sure that the program doesn't run. How do I go about doing this?

I have the four text boxes named. Cell C16 is named BuyOne (For BuyerOne), C17 is named BuyerTwo, E16 is BuyerThree and E17 is BuyerFour. This is where the user will be entering the information.

Comment: Have you tried the regular Excel Data Validation?

Comment: 'If they don't match, I want to make sure the program doesn't run' - what 'program' here? Is it just a formula that should return blank if they don't match? If so, what formula have you tried?

Comment: Use `Application.Match()` to compare each value against the list in ColO - if any of them return an error value then there is a mis-match.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071641/13252809

Check out this answer...

But in your case You don't need Else statement as you don't want to do anything when cells/range values don't match or are equal.

```
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim cell2 As Range

If (Range("cell1").Value = Range("cell2").Value) Then
    'Your task here (I believe you meant code instead of program)

End If
```

If you want precise answer then describe your question in more detail with example of what you want to do.

Comment: This is great, but how do I say if it's not in a RANGE as opposed to just a list of cells? I have the whole list labelled as Query_Buyer and it may get larger over time. How do I variably identify the list?

Comment: I tried to find a way around having to reference the whole array, but I'm getting a type mistmatch on the first line..?

If Range("BuyOne") = vbNullString Or Range("BuyOne") <> Range("O6:O50") Then
    MsgBox "Invalid Buyer Code.."
    Range("BuyOne").Select
Else: End If

Comment: I think you should share your code and example of your data if possible